# GDAL processing of GRIB2 raster prints hundreds of unsuppressable warnings

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, raster2pgsql, grib-2

I am processing some GRIB2 raster files from NCEP (weather model stuff).  An example file would be:
http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hiresw/prod/href.20180906/ensprod/href.t00z.conus.mean.f06.grib2

When I use various GDAL tools to process the file it prints this line for each of the dozens of bands in the raster:

```
Warning: Master table version == 0, was experimental
I don't have a copy, and don't know where to get one
Use meta data at your own risk
```

Ok, that warning is fine -- but it's a major problem when I process the file with `raster2pgsql` as it dumps that message dozens of times into the SQL, which causes an error when I attempt to load it into the db.  Using `gdalwarp -q` or `gdal_translate -q` still prints the message hundreds of times despite being in quiet mode.

Is there any way I can suppress this warning, either with GDAL or some sort of pre-processing of the file?

Comment: Write mail to gdal-dev mailing list with the link that you provided. Mention that the warning message is coming from this part of source code: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/frmts/grib/degrib/degrib/metaparse.cpp. But by looking at document http://apps.ecmwf.int/codes/grib/format/grib2/ctables/1/0 it feels odd that current data would use such version.

Comment: I have been told a fix has been pushed.
"I've pushed a fix in master and branch/2.3 to turn this printf() into a silent 
CPLDebug() message."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the GDAL library and has been fixed in 2.3 branch with this commit:
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/d30e7f253a5d7d6fa6c0173e3744b0409fee8a72